# Preventing Firebase deletions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've just written a small single page javascript application (for internal company use) that will be hosted on S3 and uses Firebase as the datastore.

I'm aware that a devious hacker could probably find a way to delete all the data in Firebase if they were determined enough using the javascript console.

None of the data in this application should ever be deleted.

What Firebase rules can I use to ensure data cannot be deleted by any authorised user?  It this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very broad, so it's difficult to answer. It would be a lot easier if you add some of your data structure to your question **and** show some of the things you've already tried. The [Firebase documentation for security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/) should have some good inspirational snippets for that.

Comment: The data structure is irrelevant - I just want to stop records from being removed.

Comment: Frank answer below answered it and it was simple enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, that's fairly simple:

```
".write": "!data.exists() || newData.exists()"
```

So you can write if there's either no data at the location or if you're writing new data.